# Where can I find a script that can generate every private key possible?

Tags: private-key

How do I make a script that generates every private key (bitcoin) possible?

I found one code but that didn’t worked.

Comment: Very broad question; very broad topic.  See [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 2):

In Bitcoin, a private key is just a 256-bit number, and can be represented in many, many different ways. The simplest way is to represent it with hexadecimal.

Here is a C program that prints out all the keys:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int
main()
{
    uint64_t parts[4] = {0, 0, 0, 1};

    while (!(parts[0] == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF && parts[1] == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE && parts[2] == 0xBAAEDCE6AF48A03B && parts[3] == 0xBFD25E8CD0364140)) {
        printf("%016"PRIX64"%016"PRIX64"%016"PRIX64"%016"PRIX64"\n", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
        if (++parts[3] == 0)
            if (++parts[2] == 0)
                if (++parts[1] == 0)
                    ++parts[0];
    }
}
```

However, generating every single private key would take millions and millions of years; and it is basically impossible.

There are over 10^77 possible private key combinations, which is about the number of atoms in the entire universe.